# Swift - compare words and filtering

Tags: ios, swift

i just started learning Swift and trying to make an assignment for iOS.

what i have is 4 categories of keywords, for example:

```
CategoryX: hello, bye, good, bad
CategoryY: rain, sun
CategoryZ: sun, hello, what, rain
CategoryV: yes, no, bad, music, song, note
```

what i want is to compare this categories with each other and the result will give me the keywords that are in the choosen categories.

for example if i choose to compare all the categories, the results will be: null
(because there is no keyword that appear in all categories)

but if i choose X and Z, then the result will be: hello

if Y and Z then its: sun, rain

I’m not asking from anyone to write me the code (but ofc would be nice if someone gave me a headstart), i just want little explanation of how to deal with this problem and what to use to do it the right way, can someone shed some light?

thank you

Comment: Although you are not providing any code, I would suggest to check the `Set`...

Answer (score 6):

> I’m not asking from anyone to write me the code (but ofc would be nice if someone gave me a headstart), i just want little explanation of how to deal with this problem and what to use to do it the right way, can someone shed some light?

Okay, without giving the answer away, here’s a hint about how to deal with the problem., to give you a head start.

Doesn't this assignment make you think about sets? Remember those Venn diagrams you had to make in high school? Remember the idea of the *intersection* of sets? Think about that. Think about *sets*. Hmmm... Swift has a Set struct...

If you follow up that idea, and research what a Set is in Swift, you’ll see what to do.

Comment: @JustBaron You have not understood what the question _is_. He specifically asks for a general direction, not for someone to complete his assignment for him.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

Had fun writing it so I post it here. If you aren’t finished by now then look at the result and learn from it(my motto).

I expect you to learn .forEach, .map, .filter, guard let and optional subscript, since you skipped the easy answer with Sets. Oh don’t forget closures and how they strongly capture.

```
func compare(dicts: [[String]]) -> [String] {
    var result = [String: Int]()
    dicts.forEach { arg0 in
        guard let priorResult = result[arg0.key] else {
            result[arg0.key] = arg0.value
            return
        }
        result[arg0.key] = priorResult + arg0.value
    }

    return result.filter{ arg0 in return arg0.value == dicts.count }.map{ return $0.key }
}
```

`.map, forEach and .filter` call for every item in the collection(for every key-value pair in a dictionary) thegiven closure.
`.map` returns an array of what is returned inside map.
`.filter` returns an array of items for which the closure returned true and so filtering out the items for which the closure returned false.
`.forEach` is an alternative to a for-loop.

result counts every occurance of a string.
.filter returns true for the strings which occured inside every dict.
.map maps the dictionary’s keys to a simple [String] array.

Comment: @qwe I added explanations for you. Best learn all of the functions well, they make filtering, mapping of collections much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let set1 = Set(["123","456","789"])
let set2 = Set(["123","456"])
let set3 = Set(["123"])
let res12 = set1.intersection(set2)  // ["123","456"]
let res123 = set1.intersection(set2).intersection(set3)  // ["123"]
```

Comment: Great, just give him the answer to his assignment. Now what has he _learned_?

Comment: I agree with you , but i think the site is for a full answer

Comment: He specifically _asked_ you _not_ to write him the code. So this is the not the kind of answer he was requesting.

Comment: @matt for sure you may know that 90% of site viewers copy answers without think WHY ? Anyone wants to learn can even not ask just dig for the problem until he finds it himself

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes, and that's a bad thing we should work to fight, not give up an embrace.

Comment: @Alexander for sorry to tell you that we'll be defeated , it's a human intend to select his way to learn

Comment: @DuncanC I do------Not-------Care